# Why is this object in game maker sticking in the wall?

Tags: game-maker

For whatever reason in gamemaker whenever this object (circle) is moving to the left (-x) it will stick into the wall, but when it moves to the right it acts as it should. I'll include pictures of the problem, along with the relevant code. The ball has gravity, and falls properly when on the right wall, but stays in the air on the left wall.

The code is a function that handles gravity/physics for anything that calls it. The top half (Right after isPlayer) is to handle the players gravity, so that can be ignored, but after the "else" is where the relevant code starts

[Ball not stuck in wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhHxk.png)
[Ball stuck in wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQsP0.png)

And here is the relevant code:

```
/*
runPhys(collision object, phys object, xVil, yVil, grav, environment x, environment y, isPlayer(1=player))
*/
obj=argument0;
physObj=argument1;
xVal=argument2;
yVal=argument3;
grav=argument4;
xEnv=argument5;
yEnv=argument6;
isPlayer=argument7;

with physObj{
if(isPlayer = 1){ //can ignore from here to

    ySpeed = ySpeed + yVal + grav;

    xAcc = xAcc+xVal;
    if(xAcc>5){
        xAcc = 5;
    }
    if(xAcc<-5){
        xAcc = -5;
    }
    if(position_meeting(x,y+14,obj)){
        xSpeed = 0;
        xAcc = 0;
        if(xVal = -0.2){
            xAcc = -5;
        }
        if(xVal = 0.2){
            xAcc = 5;
        }
    }

    xSpeed = xAcc;

    if(xSpeed>0){
        if((!position_meeting(x+xSpeed+6,y,obj))&&(!position_meeting(x+xSpeed+6,y+12,obj))&&(!position_meeting(x+xSpeed+6,y-12,obj))){
            x = x + xSpeed;
        }else{
            xSpeed = 0;
            xAcc = 0;
        }
    }else{
        if((!position_meeting(x-xSpeed-12,y,obj))&&(!position_meeting(x-xSpeed-12,y+12,obj))&&(!position_meeting(x-xSpeed-12,y-12,obj))){
            x = x + xSpeed;
        }else{
            xSpeed = 0;
            xAcc = 0;
        }
    }

    if(ySpeed>0){
        if(!position_meeting(x,y+ySpeed+12,obj)){
            y = y + ySpeed;
        }else{
            ySpeed = 0;
        }
    }else{
        if(!position_meeting(x,y-ySpeed-24,obj)){
            y = y + ySpeed;
        }else{
            ySpeed = 0;   
        }
    }
    if(position_meeting(x,y+12,obj)){
            y = y-1;
    }
    xSpeed = xSpeed/1.02;
}else{              //here, everything above here can be ignored

    ySpeed = ySpeed + yVal + grav;
    xSpeed = xSpeed + xVal;

    if(xSpeed>0){ //the if below checks 3 positions according to the objects bounding box, in this case its checking the right top, right middle, and right bottom of the sprite
        if((!position_meeting(x+xSpeed+(bbox_right-bbox_left)/2,y,obj))&&(!position_meeting(x+xSpeed+(bbox_right-bbox_left)/2,y+(bbox_bottom-bbox_top)/2,obj))&&(!position_meeting(x+xSpeed+(bbox_right-bbox_left)/2,y-(bbox_bottom-bbox_top)/2,obj))){
            x = x + xSpeed;
        }else{
            xSpeed = 0;
            xAcc = 0;
        }
    }else{ //this is where I believe the error to be. The above code handles moving to the right, and the below code handles moving to the left, where my problem is.
        if((!position_meeting(x-xSpeed-((bbox_right-bbox_left)/2),y,obj))&&(!position_meeting(x-(xSpeed*2)-((bbox_right-bbox_left)/2),y+(bbox_bottom-bbox_top)/2,obj))&&(!position_meeting(x-(xSpeed*2)-((bbox_right-bbox_left)/2),y-(bbox_bottom-bbox_top)/2,obj))){
            x = x + xSpeed;
        }else{
            xSpeed = 0;
            xAcc = 0;
        }
    }

    if(ySpeed>0){ //this is all y movement
        if((!position_meeting(x,y+ySpeed+(bbox_bottom-bbox_top)/2,obj))&&(!position_meeting(x+(bbox_right-bbox_left)/2,y+ySpeed+(bbox_bottom-bbox_top)/2,obj))&&(!position_meeting(x-(bbox_right-bbox_left)/2,y+ySpeed+(bbox_bottom-bbox_top)/2,obj))){
            y = y + ySpeed;
        }else{
            ySpeed = 0;
            xSpeed = 0;
        }
    }else{
        if((!position_meeting(x,y-ySpeed-(bbox_bottom-bbox_top)/2,obj))&&(!position_meeting(x+(bbox_right-bbox_left)/2,y-ySpeed-(bbox_bottom-bbox_top)/2,obj))&&(!position_meeting(x-(bbox_right-bbox_left)/2,y-ySpeed-(bbox_bottom-bbox_top)/2,obj))){
            y = y + ySpeed;
        }else{
            ySpeed = 0;  
            xSpeed = 0; 
        }
    }
    if(position_meeting(x,y+(bbox_bottom-bbox_top)/2,obj)){
            y = y-1;
            xSpeed = 0;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to make an educated guess based on what I am seeing. I do not know what your bounding boxes sizes are.

- Your code checking for anything to the right of the object is checking a little too far to the left.
- Your code checking towards the left of your object isn't checking far enough. If your objects speed is 7 and you are only checking 6 pixels to the left of the object, then you can end up inside the wall, which will allow your code checking to the right to detect a wall.
- If you are checking for only certain points and not bounding boxes, then it is possible you are simply passing the object without detecting it, depending on the walls width. I would use collision_rectangle for this sort of thing.

Also I would learn the basics of encapsulation and seperation of concerns. By putting your code into separate functions you make it a lot easier to debug and to read.

Comment: I am using collision points, and you make a good point that I should use collision rectangles. I figured out my problem though. When I hit the left key, it sets the speed to -5, but in my code I am checking the position x-(speed), but I should be checking x+speed because the speed is a negative. Thanks for the help though!